# How can I create multiple Subscriptions for presence with graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying subscribe to the user presence of my team members using the graph API subscription. I am using the following code to do that:

```
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "https://myNotificationURLEndPoint/notification",
"resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in ('sample_user_AAD_ID')",
"expirationDateTime": "2023-10-11T12:32:45.9356913Z",
"clientState": "1234"
```

I am successfully able to create the subscription.

As per the current limit mentioned in the Microsoft Documentation, in one subscription we can subscribe to 650 members however my team has more than 1,000 members in the team.

So, when I am trying to create multiple subscriptions to get the presence notification for all my team members, it's not working and gives the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Conflict; Reason: A subscription already exists. It must be deleted before another can be made.]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-10-11T06:08:19",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Can I create more than one subscription with same access token? if no then how can I implement my requirement? is there any work around that I can do?

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple subscriptions using same access token.